# Page Routing with parameters or POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have index.js like this

```
var hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/landing" component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path="/" component={Components} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

At first, User opens the `landing` page and then go to `/` page.

in `Landing` page ,there is a button to move

```
<Button 
      variant="contained"
      color="secondary"
      style={{margin:"50px"}} href="/">
      go next        
</Button>
```

However here I want to move `/` page with `POST` parameters

```
id=12
name=myname
from=landing
```

At first I tried with GET parameter `/?id=12&name=myname&from=landing`

I can't use `useQuery` in class Component. I am not familiar with `function component` so mainly use 'class component`

How can I make this???

Or is there any good way to give the parameters when switching another page without POST nor GET?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.search` API, just put following function into a `JS` file and `import` it where you need:

`src/utils/query.js`

```js
   export function getQuery() {
      let b = window.location.search
        .slice(1)
        .split("&")
        .map(qStr => qStr.split("="))
        .reduce((acc, inc) => {
          acc[inc[0]] = inc[1];
          return acc;
        }, {});
        return b;
    }
```

and where you want to use it

```js
import getQuery from './utils/query';
.
.
.
    let q = getQuery();
    if(q.lenght){
        let name = q['name']
        let id = q['id']
        let from = q['from']
    }
    //Or directly call it
    let name = getQuery()['name']
    let id = getQuery()['id']
    let from = getQuery()['from']
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works and simply solve my problem.